# no id for model?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, self-reference

I get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Class:0x007fe1dc4e3bb0>
```

when defining a sql call in my model user:

```
  RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITION = "(user_id = #{id}) OR user_id IN (SELECT user_b_id AS user_id FROM user_follows WHERE user_follows.user_a_id = #{id} )"
```

Model code

```
has_many :recent_events,
    :class_name  => "Activity",
    :finder_sql  => 'SELECT activities.* FROM activities
                    WHERE ' + RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITION + '
                    ORDER BY activities.created_at DESC',
    :counter_sql => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activities
                    WHERE ' + RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITION
```

Everything works fine until i introduce this recent_events ...

Comment: Can you post more of your model code, maybe the whole method using the sql query?

Comment: String interpolation happens when the string is defined; if that's a class constant, there's no meaningful ID at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a `User` class or something similar, and I'm assuming when you use `#{id}`, you're really just trying to use the user's id. So I would do this instead:

```
RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITION = "(user_id = users.id) OR user_id IN (SELECT user_b_id AS user_id FROM user_follows WHERE user_follows.user_a_id = users.id )"
```